# In C++, if a funcion takes in a const std::string& as input, can I always call with std::move() on the string input?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I don't know much about the function, except it takes a `const std::string&`, and I want to call this function from inside a class, and the string input I'm sending in is returned from an instance function on this class.

Is `std::move()` usage here always safe and more performant, given what we know?

```
//In some header file:
void some_func_I_only_know_its_signature(const std::string& string_input);

public MyClass{
   public:
     void myFunc(){
         some_func_I_only_know_its_signature(std::move(getMyString()));
     }

  private:
    std::string getMyString(){
        return myString;
    }

    std::string myString_;

};
```

Comment: why do you think you would need `std::move` ? Whats wrong with `some_func_I_only_know_its_signature(myString_);` ?

Comment: *"Is std::move usage here always safe and more perfomant, given what we know?"* `std::move` has no effect here. `getMyString` returns by value, so it is already an rvalue. "Given what we know" implies you've been misinformed or misunderstand what `std::move` does.

Comment: aren't we saving a copy operation by calling std::move ? @FrançoisAndrieux

Comment: It's safe but serves no purpose, and it won't improve performance. A function that isn't designated to take an rvalue reference won't benefit from a value being converted to one, and a value which is already an rvalue won't benefit from being converted to one either.

Comment: the functions argument is a reference. Nothing is being copied. You do introduce a copy by calling the getter (for no obvious reason)

Comment: @user1008636 No, you're not saving a copy.  `std::move` just casts to an rvalue, which the string returned by `getMyString` already is by virtue of being returned by value.

Comment: @user1008636 No. With or without `std::move`, the `string_input` reference will bind the return value of `getMyString` which lives until the end of the full expression.

Comment: _"aren't we saving a copy operation by calling std::move?"_  If you are not sure where a copy operation is happening, it's premature to decide that `std::move` will eliminate that copy operation.  `std::move` only casts a value to an xvalue.  You are casting a prvalue to an xvalue, which in the best circumstances does nothing.

Comment: While getter functions are to be avoided if possible, a private getter function is rather useless.

Comment: Calling `std::move` directly on a function call expression is in most cases either semantically wrong (if the function returns a lvalue reference), a complete no-op (if it returns a rvalue reference) or potentially detrimental to performance by making copy elision impossible (if it returns by-value). You should use `std::move` when you pass _variables_ than you are not going to use anymore after the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::move` actually does absolutely nothing here:

```
some_func_I_only_know_its_signature(std::move(getMyString()));
```

The return value of getMyString is already an rvlaue. The thing is std::move actually doesn't move anything. This is a common misconception. All it does is cast an lvalue to an rvalue. If the value is an rvalue and has a move constructor (sdt::string does) it will get moved. But in this case, since the function does not expect an rvalue reference either way you are just going to pass a reference to the return value of `getMyString()` So you can just:

```
some_func_I_only_know_its_signature(getMyString());
```

That being said the most performant ways is to just:

```
some_func_I_only_know_its_signature(myString_);
```

The function expects a const& which means it only wants read access. Your `getMyString()` function creates a **copy** of `myString_` and returns it. You don't have to create a copy here, you can just pass a reference to your string directly. get/set functions are usually used for controlled public access to a private field from **outside** the class.